# React clear form in Component from Context

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and have UserForm component that have form, and ResetData component. All of my data is stored on UserContext. Now I created function inside ResetData component that will call UserContext and set user data to empty. But I am not sure how can I delete from in UserForm component... can someone point me in right direction?

UserForm.jsx

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../contexts/UserContext";

import "../../styles/user-form.css";
import "../../styles/buttons.css";

function UserForm() {
  const [formUsername, setFormUsername] = useState("");
  const { fetchUser } = useContext(UserContext);

  function onUpdateUsername(event) {
    setFormUsername(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchUser(formUsername);
  }

  return (
    <div className="user-form">
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <label className="label-username mb-20" htmlFor="input-username">
          User
        </label>
        <input
          className="input-username mb-20"
          id="input-username"
          onChange={onUpdateUsername}
          placeholder="Enter git account"
        />
        <button className="button button-submit" type="submit">
          Get details
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserForm;
```

ResetData.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../contexts/UserContext";

import "../../styles/buttons.css";

function ResetData() {
  const { resetUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <div className="text-align-center">
      <button className="button button-reset" onClick={resetUser}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ResetData;
```

UserContext.jsx

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [userReposData, setUserReposData] = useState([]);

  const fetchUser = (user) => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => setUserData(data));
    fetchUserRepo(user);
  };

  const fetchUserRepo = (user) => {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}/repos`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => setUserReposData(data));
  };

  const resetUser = () => {
    setUser("");
    setUserData([]);
    setUserReposData([]);
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{ user, setUser, fetchUser, userData, userReposData, resetUser }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const UserContext = createContext();
```

full code can be found on [myGit](https://github.com/goranGG/react-git-fetcher)

Comment: you want to clean input after resetting ?

Comment: @mirik999 yes, thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move form state to Context ,

```
I noted changes like // *



export function UserContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [formUsername, setFormUsername] = useState(""); // *
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
  const [userReposData, setUserReposData] = useState([]);

  const resetUser = () => {
   setUser("");
   setUserData([]);
   setUserReposData([]);
   setFormUsername("") //*
  };

 return (
<UserContext.Provider
  value={{ user, setUser, fetchUser, userData, userReposData, 
  formUsername, setFormUsername,  resetUser }} //*
>
  ....
```

In UseForm component add value prop to Input to get subscribe to the state from context

```
function UserForm() {
  const { fetchUser, formUsername, setFormUsername } = useContext(UserContext); // *

 
        <input
          value={formUsername} // *
          className="input-username mb-20"
          id="input-username"
          onChange={onUpdateUsername}
          placeholder="Enter git account"
        />
```

Comment: yea thats good idea, but wondering from architectural point is this necessary or there is another way? I mean this is small application, I guess then I need use multiple Contexts if I need this only in some part of my app?

Comment: it's okay, your context does one job - handling user things, but you can also can use global state for this purpose something like zustand ( lightweight or recoil from facebook ).

Comment: Context in react like a dependency injection if you know what is it. So it would be good to use one context for one thing. Dont mix multiple entities. e.g. Product and User in one context.

Comment: I see... that what got me confused even its Form for user, it doesnt matter that its Form. Since it is handling username its OK to be inside of UserContext